# GUI design doesn't update when button pressed in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to change colors on  a graphic view to simulate traffic lights but I'm not sure why the colors doesn't change when the start button is clicked

```
    void MainWindow::empezar_ciclo(){

    sleep_asm(3);  // waits a certain time to change color
    semdirE->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red)); // changes the color of a drawed dot
}
```

```
    void MainWindow::on_start_clicked(){

  
    MainWindow:ui->start->hide();
   
   empezar_ciclo();}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].  Note also that `sleep_asm(3);` will block the GUI thread making it unresponsive.  If you want to perform an action periodically or after a certain delay have a look at [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html).

Comment: Seems to be the same question cross-posted on https://forum.qt.io/topic/137363/traffic-light.  (The first hit when I searched for `qt sleep_asm`, to see if it was a standard function.  It's not.  But assuming it blocks that thread for 3 seconds, yeah that's a problem.)

Comment: Hi checking in the forum i finally found out how to work it out using process events from QCoreApplication , there was a way with multithreading i was running out of time tho and got no time to learn that  and today have to presesent thanks

Answer (score -2):

it should work after all its following the program common order